Magnifier modifier with AndroidView with camera preview
I want to implement the magnifier modifer on my camera preview.
What Im trying right now:
@Composable
fun CameraScreen() {
    val previewView = remember { SurfaceView(context) }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = { previewView })

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .magnifier(
                    sourceCenter = { Offset.Zero },
                    zoom = 2f,
                ),
        )
    }
}

But it only draws a box where the magnifier should be, but the box is not magnifying the preview. Anyone have any ideas?

The magnifer modifier does not work directly with AndroidView as it is designed for composable content.To apply magnification over a camera preview, render the preview using a TextureView or SurfaceView and integrate it into Compose via AndroidView. For magnification, overlay a composable with the magnifier modifier on top of the preview. Alternatively, capture the preview into a composable layer using Modifier.graphicsLayer for seamless Compose integration.
@Composable
fun CameraScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    // PreviewView setup
    val previewView = remember {
        PreviewView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        }
    }

    // Start camera with previewView
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context).get()
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
            it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
        }

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
    }

    // Compose layout with magnifier
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = { previewView }
        )

        // Apply magnifier on top of the preview
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .magnifier(
                    sourceCenter = { Offset.Zero }, // Customize based on interaction
                    zoom = 2f
                )
                .size(100.dp), // Size of the magnification effect
        )
    }
}

